# Room database is working fine in Debug build but not working in Release build

Tags: android, android-room, proguard, minify

Hi StackOverflow community, recently I have updated my Android project to Gradle 7.5 and Kotlin to 1.7.20. But since then I couldn't get the Room DB working in the release build. On Debug build it works alright.

Gradle version: 7.5
Kotlin version: 1.7.20
Room version: 2.4.3

App level build configs:

```
debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [buildType                   : "-Debug",
                                    crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "false"]
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [buildType                   : "",
                                    crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "true"]
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

I believe it has something to do with Pro-guard rules but couldn't find the right rules which will work in my case. Kindly if anyone can guide me what I'm missing here and how to fix this issue. Any help would highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wnat proguard rules have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely facing an issue with proguard obfuscating `Room` classes or your defined `Entities`. Try this:

```
-keep class androidx.room.RoomDataBase { *; }
-keep class androidx.room.Room { *; }
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
-keep @androidx.room.Entity class *
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**
```

reference from architecture sample: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/main/app/proguard-rules.pro